# How to remove an unwanted tilde in the citations?

Tags: bibtex, babel, accents

I'm inserting citations with bibtex and getting an unwanted tilde before the author's names. How could I prevent this behavior?

The headers of my document are

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

[image: Citation with unwanted tilde]

Comment: You haven't given enough code to diagnose the problem.  First, the `sig-alternate` class isn't in a standard TeXLive distribution; where does it come from. But if you can reproduce the problem with the `article` class, then using this class isn't part of the problem.  Second, your question is a problem with the bibliography, but you don't show what methods you are using to produce it with.  Please make a complete minimal document that shows the problem. It might also be helpful to paste an entry from your `.bib` file too (or do all entries have the same problem?).

Comment: Sorry, I'm both a noob to LaTeX, MacTex and this forum. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies with an interaction between the `sig-alternate` class and the Spanish option of `babel`. The Spanish option of `babel` implements various shorthands, and you need to turn off (at least) the one for the tilde. Since you are using `utf8` input, it's likely that you don't need the tilde shorthand, so you can turn it off as a package option, by adding `es-notilde`.  If for some reason you are using the shorthands in the document, you can add

```
\spanishdeactivate{~}
```

just before your `\bibliography` command.

Here's a minimal working example (like the one you should have provided) which solves the problem (remove the `es-notilde` option to reproduce the problem).

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{Sobin1976,
    Author = {N Sobin},
    Journal = {Linguistic Inquiry},
    Pages = {726-728},
    Title = {Pragmatics of Lurking},
    Volume = {7},
    Year = {1976}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage[english,spanish,es-notilde]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\begin{document}
\cite{Sobin1976}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```