# Removing tilde (~) from IEEE references when using bstctlcite

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I discovered the bstctlcite option which IEEE includes as part of the [IEEEtran class](https://icitst.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/bibliography-files-unix.pdf). Specifically, I am using the `ctlmax_names_forced_etal` option to shorten a long list of author names. My document was written for a conference, so I was using ieeeconf.cls, not IEEEtran.cls. I had to add the following to my preamble (note, taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431089/14277), because the example in the IEEEtrans documentation gave me an error "Use of \bstctlcite doesn't match its definition.

```
\bstctlcite{"): 
\makeatletter
\def\bstctlcite{\@ifnextchar[{\@bstctlcite}{\@bstctlcite[@auxout]}}
\def\@bstctlcite[#1]#2{\@bsphack
  \@for\@citeb:=#2\do{%
    \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb}%
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\csname #1\endcsname{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi}%
  \@esphack}
\makeatother
```

Reducing the number of names worked excellently, but it also introduced a tilde (~) in the author names i.e. `A.~Nother et al.` How do I get rid of the tilde?

This question is very similar to [How to remove an unwanted tilde in the citations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/182664/14277) especially the title, but it has a different answer, so I don't think it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in the other options set as part of the `bstctlcite`. I had taken the "default options" from the IEEEtrans documentation:

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
CTLuse_article_number = "yes",
CTLuse_paper = "yes",
CTLuse_forced_etal = "no",
CTLmax_names_forced_etal = "10",
CTLnames_show_etal = "1",
CTLuse_alt_spacing = "yes",
CTLalt_stretch_factor = "4",
CTLdash_repeated_names = "yes",
CTLname_format_string = "{f.˜}{vv˜}{ll}{, jj}",
CTLname_latex_cmd = ""
CTLname_url_prefix = "[Online]. Available:"
}
```

and modified `CTLuse_forced_etal = "yes"` and `CTLmax_names_forced_etal = "3"`. The tilde comes from the `CTLname_format_string`, which I modified to become: `CTLname_format_string = "{f. }{vv }{ll}{, jj}"`

There is a risk that somebody's initial and name will be split over multiple lines, but since I am restricting to just 3 names, they will usually all fit on one line.